# Parent are not set anymore after saveElement()

Tags: entries, structure, events, saveentry, parents

In this code I try to create a new Entry and set a Parent to it.
The sectionId and the typeId are actually the same.

```
$navigationItem = new Entry();
$navigationItem->typeId = 4;
$navigationItem->sectionId = $navigationSection->id;
$navigationItem->title = $entry->title;
$navigationItem->setParent($herbsNavigationEntry);

$navigationItem->setFieldValue('navLink', '/tags/' . $entry->slug);

if (!Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($navigationItem)) {
    Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "' . $entry->title . '"', __METHOD__);
}
```

Before saving I get this:

[image]

But after the `Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($navigationItem)`,
the parent disappears.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `newParentId`:

```
$navigationItem = new Entry();
$navigationItem->typeId = 4;
$navigationItem->sectionId = $navigationSection->id;
$navigationItem->title = $entry->title;
$navigationItem->newParentId = $herbsNavigationEntry->id;

$navigationItem->setFieldValue('navLink', '/tags/' . $entry->slug);

if (!Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($navigationItem)) {
    Craft::error('Couldn’t save the entry "' . $entry->title . '"', __METHOD__);
}
```

Comment: That works fine. Anyway PHPStorm tells me: Field 'newParentId' is marked as @internal. 
But it works. Thank you.

Comment: Should also mention `newParentId` was removed in Craft 4, so use `$navigationItem->setParentId($herbsNavigationEntry->id);`